# How to make the inner block of a nested plsql block pragma autonomous

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have a nested plsql where the first needs to be done:

- First, in the outer block insert a value '1' in table "A"; print the success message. NO COMMIT on this one.
- Then, build an inner block inserting another value '2' in table "A" and COMMIT the same; print the success message
- Come back to the outer block and then rollback the value '1' which was inserted before calling the inner block (please don’t delete the record, Rollback the same); print the success message
- Check if the table "A" is having 2 records, then program should exist with error.

So basically in the end the table should have just one record-the value 2

```
declare
  count_num integer;
  procedure second_commit is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin

    insert into Table_A values(1);
    dbms_output.put_line('Successfully entered 1');

    begin
      insert into Table_A values(2);
      commit;
      dbms_output.put_line('Successfully entered 2 and committed');

  end second_commit;

  rollback;

  dbms_output.put_line('Rollback Done');

  select count(*) into count_num from Table_A;

  if (count_num=2) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exit with error');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Normal Exit');
  end if;

end;
```

If I follow the above code, the table commits both records and then rollbacks to the last commit meaning it wont rollback any record
In the above code basically I need to make the inner block (where 2 is being inserted) pragma autonomous or do something due to which the insertion of value 1 before the call of inner block rollbacks and only the record with value 2 remains

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The second_commit procedure should be autonomous and should do only the second insert and commit:

```
declare
count_num integer;

procedure second_insert_and_commit is pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  insert into Table_A values(2);
  commit;
  dbms_output.put_line('Successfully entered 2 and committed');
end second_insert_and_commit;

begin

  insert into Table_A values(1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Successfully entered 1');

  second_insert_and_commit;

  rollback;

  dbms_output.put_line('Rollback Done');

  select count(*) into count_num from Table_A;
  if (count_num=2) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exit with error');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Normal Exit');
  end if;
end;
```